# How to use substring to return list of matching values in Excel

Tags: excel, list, substring

This is an excel function question.

I have a list of 400K+ strings. Many of them are variations of the same name. I need a way to automatically match any list entry with a string. So if 5 items in my list all contain the string 'ldl', I want a way to return them.

I have the following piece of code that I have verified works for an exact match. D2 is the value I want to match and a2:a11 is the range I am searching.
I simply drag the cell handle down as may rows as I need and it will match that many instances in the list

> =INDEX($A$2:$A$11, SMALL(IF($D$2=$A$2:$A$11, ROW($A$2:$A$11)-ROW($A$2)+1), ROW(1:1)))

What I would like it to do is return the value in Col A if D2 matches the cell's contents via a substring match.

I tried the following but while syntactically correct it is returning just the first value in the list.

> =INDEX($B$2:$B$11, SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$2,$A$2:$A$11)), ROW($B$2:$B$11)-ROW($B$2)+1), ROW(1:1)))

The image I included demonstrates the current exact matching functionality. I'd like A2:A11 to be able to contain D2 with any number of characters before or after the seach value. For example, in the screenshot I would like to return A11.[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some sample strings along with expected output would go a long way here

Comment: Done, added image. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine `INDEX`, `AGGREGATE` and `SEARCH` functions:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$11,AGGREGATE(15,6,(SEARCH($D$2,$A$2:$A$11)>0)*ROW($A$2:$A$11)-1,ROW()-1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's your first formula modified to use the SEARCH function:

`=INDEX($A$2:$A$11, SMALL(IF(IFERROR(SEARCH($D$2,$A$2:$A$11),FALSE), ROW($A$2:$A$11)-ROW($A$2)+1), ROW(1:1)))`